# NodeJS get the mysql query result

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a table containing an ISBN number and a the available number of books. I want to make a query to to ISBN number and get the response about the number of the books with this ID, but I don't know how to write the proper function to get the query result?

```
db.checkPeldanyszam( rentISBN, response, callback) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).render('error', { message: `Insertion unsuccessful: ${err.message}` });
      } else {
        console.log(err);
        next();
      }
});
```

```
exports.checkPeldanyszam = (req,callback) => {
  console.log(req);
  const query = `SELECT Peldanyszam, IF(Peldanyszam>0, "Jo", "Hibas") as isOkay FROM konyv
  WHERE ISBN=${req};`
  pool.query(query,callback);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi there! It is not entirely clear what you are asking. Isn't your `checkPeldanyszam`-function querying the db as you are expecting?

Comment: Your first code-block is not valid javascript. There might be missing a parenthesis.